# Running a query in BigQuery that was prepared by Google Administrators and get an error at almost every line

Tags: google-bigquery

SELECT
stn,

date,
-- Use the IF function to replace 9999.9 values, which the dataset description explains is the default value when temperature is missing, with NULLs instead.
IF(

```
    temp=9999.9,
    NULL,
    temp) AS temperature,
```

-- Use the IF function to replace 999.9 values, which the dataset description explains is the default value when wind speed is missing, with NULLs instead.
IF(

```
    wdsp="999.9",
    NULL,
    CAST(wdsp AS Float64)) AS wind_speed,
```

-- Use the IF function to replace 99.99 values, which the dataset description explains is the default value when precipitation is missing, with NULLs instead.

```
IF(

   prcp=99.99,
   0,
   prcp) AS precipitation
```

FROM
`bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020`
WHERE
stn="725030" -- La Guardia

OR stn="744860" -- JFK
ORDER BY
date DESC,
stn ASC

Comment: could you be more specific as what is the error you are getting. I executed the query at my end and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance. You are right, by the end of the query, it worked although I got errors along the way. I'm beginning to see that every error is not important until you have completed the full query.

Comment: yes @Merle. :-) I am glad you got it.